# Parallel combination of resistance

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Why does the Equivalent resistance decrease when we connect resistors in parallel? I know current divides and potential difference is constant but my question is that if Equivalent resistance have same flow of current as indiviual resistance then why parallel equivalent resistance is smaller than smallest indiviual resistance. I dont want derivation of parallel resistance formula.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resistors in series vs parallel](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90830/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to think of the solution to this question, apart from the usual equation for parallel resistors, is in terms of the equation for the resistance of a resistor:

$R=\rho L/A $

Two parallel resistors can effectively be thought of as one equivalent resistor with a larger A (area).  Since $L$, the resistor's length, and $\rho$, the resistivity, are roughly the same in as before, the resistance is smaller.

Comment: This answer would be improved if the variables were defined.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Parallel resistances]

We apply a potential $V$ across the two parallel resistors, $R_1$ and $R_2$.

The total current $I_T$ is the sum of two components:

$$I_T=I_1+I_2\tag{1}$$
Ohm's law applies to both resistors, so:
$$I_1=\frac{V}{R_1}$$
$$I_2=\frac{V}{R_2}$$

Substitute both into $(1)$:
$$I_T=\frac{V}{R_1}+\frac{V}{R_2}=V\Big(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\Big)$$
With $R_T$ the *total* (or "equivalent") resistance we apply Ohm on the whole circuit:
$$I_T=\frac{V}{R_T}$$
$$\implies \frac{V}{R_T}=V\Big(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\Big)$$
$$\frac{1}{R_T}=\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}$$
$$R_T=\frac{R_1R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$
Think of the flow of electrons as analogous to the flow of water through a pipe (or pipes). Due to viscous forces, pressure ('potential') needs to be applied to pump the water through the 'resisting' pipe(s), By running two pipes in parallel, we reduce the resistance to flow.